# Sqlite query for dealing with the date

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the data in the Sqlite DB in this format..

```
  month     year     FarmerCode     Value
   12       2012        1             10
   9        2012        1             25
   12       2012        2             5
   10       2012        2             12
   ..........
   ..........
```

I have to find out the average value with respect to FarmerCode. Suppose for FarmerCode 1, the two months are `12 and 9`. SO the diffrence is `12 - 9 = 3`

And then the `average = (25+10)/diffrence(which is 3 here)`

**What will be the query to find this?**

And at last if the date moves to next year as shown here

```
  month     year     FarmerCode     Value

   1        **2013**        4             20
   10       **2012**        4             50
```

This time I can't  do `1-10`

**So what will be the possible sqlite query to find the difference between two months as per the FarmerCode and the corresponding average, the formula to find the average will be**

```
average = (value1+value2)/diffrence of months
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The idea**:

The trick is to multiply the year by 12 and add it up with the month.

```
(2013*12+1)-(2012*12+10) = 3
```

**The SQL query**:

A working SQL query tested in sqlite for this is:

```
SELECT 
    FarmerCode, 
    SUM(value) / (MAX(12 * year + month) - MIN(12 * year + month)) 
FROM 
    t 
GROUP BY 
    FarmerCode;
```

By using `GROUP BY FarmerCode` you get one result row per different `FarmerCode` value. `sum()`, `min()`, and `max()` aggregates therefore all values of rows with equal `FarmerCode`. The `min()` and `max()` construct in this query works properly, if there are two rows for each `FarmerCode` value.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can find the months difference by using this method

```
private int monthsdiff(int m1,int year1, int m2,int year2)
{
    int yeardiff = year2 - year1;
    int mondiff  = m2 - m1;
    mondiff = yeardiff*12+mondiff;
    return mondiff;
}
```

Comment: Actually I need query for solving this stuff

Comment: [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) are the date functions for sqlite. check once this may help you